# Rewriterule doesn't work on mobile device but it does for desktop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I enter from my computer I can see the web correctly but when I try to enter from a mobile phone I get an internal error 500. In fact, if you use PageSpeed

You'll be able to see this error.

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC, QSA,L]
```

The site is www.cuponalfa.com. If you enter, you'll get a header location to www.cuponalfa.com/negocio.

Please let me know if you have any idea about what it could be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a [rewrite rule targeting mobiles](https://gist.github.com/chrillo/1403965) that may mess things up. Also I believe there is not meant to be a space between "NC," and "QSA"? The space caused an internal server error on my end

Comment: It was a problem on the server side and my hosting provider fixed it, thanks